# How can I keep my dog from going stir crazy while recuperating?

Tags: dogs

A couple of days ago, my dog cut the pads of one of his paws. It was pretty nasty, but really not too bad. We took him to the vet to get it wrapped up and the vet recommended that he rest and take it easy.

This makes sense. Any time he steps on the foot, it is going to reopen the wound. Running around will be worse. The problem is that we are normally out running around or playing at the dog park for an hour or more everyday. He's a husky with plenty of energy.

My little guy is going to go nuts if he can't out for walks or for play for 2 weeks. Then he's going to drive me nuts!

Anyone have any strategies, games, treats, toys, foods or something else that has helped them in the past through a similar situation? Is there such a thing as puppy-xanax? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be tough on a dog and owner!

I can recommend some things that might help:

- **Mental stimulation**: training and training games definitely also help tire a dog out. Focus on things that get him to think - like 'guess which cup the food is under'. For training why not try teaching things like stay, bed and even roll over which keep pressure off his foot.
- **Get out of the house**: If he is used to getting out you should try think of something to allow him to still see the outside world. Some options might be to take him for drives, to dog-friendly restaurants, just sit somewhere and watch the world go by. Probably avoid the dog park because he would get too excited.
- **Teach him to chew**: If you haven't done chew-training yet now is a good time to start. Chewing is basically puppy-xanax so get some chew toys for him. Stuffing a Kong is a great way to start. I use my dogs pellets mixed with some treats, then I pour a bit of boiling water over to soften and freeze it. This is healthier than some of the other options.

Definitely watch his weight - he will be doing a lot less exercise so maybe cut down on his food intake a bit as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Well that was exactly What i was going to say. Adding big and calm walks leashed could be a solution too.